# iOS iPhone finger paint-like app, is there a built-in canvas or open source projects to help me get started?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, drawing, inkcanvas

I need to implement on-screen drawing feature within one of my apps. I would imagine it would be an on-screen transparent overlay. I'm looking to be able to **trace the finger path and leave a line, select colors and have erase/undo feature.**
 I did some research of what's currently on the app store, and a lot of those apps look similar and use similar brushes.

Something tells me that they look too much alike for this to be a coincidence. **Does apple provide any built-in finger painting canvas, or are there some widely-known open source projects for on-screen drawing?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the GLPaint project, which you can get [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html).

Other than that, you could use CoreGraphics & [`-touchesBegan:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a) if you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same thing while looking for examples when I got started with drawing, so I released my efforts as a sample project called [SimpleDrawing](https://bitbucket.org/nwoolls/simpledrawing). I tried to keep things basic while supporting most/all of the standard drawing tools and operations.